# How does 'LIMIT' parameter work in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

I have 4000 rows for example, and I define X limit.

The query stops after it finds X rows? or the query finds all the rows and then takes X rows from the found rows?

Thank you.

Comment: `LIMIT` is not a SQL standard keyword, so which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limit-optimization.html):

> If you use LIMIT row_count with ORDER BY, MySQL ends the sorting as
>   soon as it has found the first row_count rows of the sorted result,
>   rather than sorting the entire result. If ordering is done by using an
>   index, this is very fast. If a filesort must be done, all rows that
>   match the query without the LIMIT clause must be selected, and most or
>   all of them must be sorted, before it can be ascertained that the
>   first row_count rows have been found. In either case, after the
>   initial rows have been found, there is no need to sort any remainder
>   of the result set, and MySQL does not do so.

So it looks like it's **possible** that the entire result set is known before the `LIMIT` is applied. But MySQL will try everything it can not to do so. And you can help it by providing useful indexes that match your queries.

EDIT: Furthermore, if the set is not sorted it terminates the `SELECT` operation as soon as it's streamed enough rows to the result set.

Answer (score 24):

SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT `0, 10`

This will display the **first 10 results** from the database.

SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT *`5, 5`*

This will show records **6, 7, 8, 9, and 10**

It's like telling `MySql;` I want you to start counting from **5+1 or the 6th record**,  but Select only upto **5 records**

Comment: This does not really answer the question. The question clearly asks how mysql treats the LIMIT close and not what it does with it.

Comment: @willa Please re-Read the Question. it says: **How does 'LIMIT' parameter work in sql?** notice the word: *Work* ... And my *answer* show how it works ... And please let me have my _UpVotes_ back. Thank You! :)

Comment: I still think you are not answering the question. Read both the title and the body.

Comment: Consider this: 
**I have 4000 rows for example, and I define X limit.**

=>> ((catch this line)) <<== **_The query stops after it finds X rows?_**  **or** the query =>> ((and this line)) **finds all the rows and then takes X rows from the found rows?** ....MY_ANSWER Simply says that: if Given: `SELECT * FROM your_table LIMIT 0, 10 // MySql will return 10 rows starting from 0` and in `SELECT * FROM your_table LIMIT 5, 5 //MySql will Return rows Starting from the 6th & 7th, 8th, 9th, and 10th` ... **How doesn't this ANSWER Help the User?** .... (some how) _I feel Bullied by your comments_

Comment: Sorry ErickBest I am in no way trying to bully you. I was looking for an explanation of how LIMIT works and honestly your explanation didn't give any more knowledge than I already have. I have re-read the question and your answer sorry but no thank you, you are not answering.

Comment: Look at your answer, it says what mysql will return given LIMIT clause without clarifying whether mysql fetches all matching rows and then pick the corresponding rows constrained by LIMIT or it simply fetch the records and when it hits the desired number of records asked by LIMIT it stops, which is what the question is asking. Look at the accepted answer, it states clearly what yours lacks! Sorry pal it is the question not me.

Comment: Peace Pal!... Somehow, _My Answer_ illustrates the _Accepted Answer_ if you salad both you get one great and _Supreme Answer_ ...... that is why this answer has helped many with the same issue that have visited this page.

Answer (score 4):

**Introduction to MySQL LIMIT clause**

The following illustrates the LIMIT clause syntax with two arguments:

```
SELECT 
select_list
FROM
table_name
LIMIT [offset,] row_count;
```

- The `offset` specifies the offset of the first row to return. The offset of the first row is 0, not 1.
- The `row_count` specifies the maximum number of rows to return.

The following picture illustrates the LIMIT clause:

[image]

Therefore, these two clauses are equivalent:

```
> LIMIT row_count; 
> LIMIT 0 , row_count;
```

The following picture illustrates the evaluation order of the LIMIT clause in the SELECT statement:

[image]

Comment: really good explanation, appreciate

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're thinking about MySQL, in which according to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limit-optimization.html), the answer is it depends. If you're using a `LIMIT` (without a `HAVING`), then:

- If you are selecting only a few rows with `LIMIT`, MySQL uses indexes
  in some cases when normally it would prefer to do a full table scan.
- As soon as MySQL has sent the required number of rows to the client, it aborts the query unless you are using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.

There are a few other cases which you should read about in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limit-optimization.html).

Answer (score 1):

It stops after it found the number of rows specified in the LIMIT clause. This can be verified with a large amount of data. It retrieves the result in a time that is not possible if it is getting all the rows of the table and filtering after that.

Comment: In an unordered query. If you're asking for explicit ordering it's possible (though unlikely) that it will sort the entire set before it's reached the limit requested.

Answer (score -3):

If you are using MS SQL Server, then you can write it as given below.

```
Select TOP [x]

*
From MyTable
```

Hope it helps.

Vamyip

Comment: I think the OP is asking about the technical implementation, not how to write the query.

Comment: If he's asking about LIMIT, he's quite clearly not in MSSQL, as it doesn't **have** LIMIT.