# Need enlightenment about the complexity of query posts

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

There's something I try to understand about the process  of querying posts in wordpress:

Lets say I have this code:

```
$args = array{
    'cat' => 'animals',
    'posts_per_page' => 3
}

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

So theoretically wordpress go to the database, going through all posts, and for each post, from the first to the last, it "asks" the post for it's category, if the answer is "animals" it grabs that post and move to the one after, if the category is something else, it skip that post and move to the one after. And repeat that process n times?
Or, since I set `posts_per_page` to 3, after the third post that matchs "animals", the process it stops?

If the answer is the first, How can I optimize the code if, let's say I have 300 posts under "animals", but I need only the latest 3. How can I tell wordpress to stop checking after the third one that match  "animals"?

I'm asking this since I'm working on a custom theme for site with more then 40000 posts, the homepage need to have at least 5 different queries like the one above, and I want to make it as efficient as possible.

I hope that's  make sense.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, it doesn't go through all posts and "ask" for the category.  In the database query, it only *asks* for posts that are in the category, so the query only gets the 3 specific posts.  The database handles the WHERE and LIMIT clauses built-in, so it is very efficient.  ALSO, WordPress does a lot of caching automatically, so it reduces the load on the database even further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into the WP core, you will see this piece of code in `wp-includes/query.php`, in the `get_posts` function:

```
if ( empty($q['offset']) ) {
    $pgstrt = absint( ( $page - 1 ) * $q['posts_per_page'] ) . ', ';
} else { // we're ignoring $page and using 'offset'
    $q['offset'] = absint($q['offset']);
    $pgstrt = $q['offset'] . ', ';
}
$limits = 'LIMIT ' . $pgstrt . $q['posts_per_page'];
```

This mean that the `posts_per_page` parameter is translated to a basic sql `LIMIT`. So you don't have to worry for performance on this side.

[How does 'LIMIT' parameter work in sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6736573/3305116)

Considering the `wp_terms_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id`, `wp_terms_taxonomy.term_id_taxonomy`, `wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id` are all indexes the `LIMIT` should not select all rows, as far as I know.

Comment: Ok, I tought to put a counter variable and increase it by 1 in every while iteration. the while loop stop when counter = 3 (if posts_per_page is set to 3). But according to your comment it's unnecessary, right?

Comment: No the while is done on the SQL result, which is alreay limited to 3 - the limit is done on MySQL side, not on the PHP side. As a side note, if you're worried about performance, I would suggest to get a cache plugin like [W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/).