# Surprising timing stats for sql queries

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, timing

I have two queries whose timing parameters I want to analyze.

The first query is taking much longer than the second one while in my opinion it should be the other way round.Any Explanations?

First query:

```
select mrn
from EncounterInformation
limit 20;
```

Second query:

```
select enc.mrn, fl.fileallocationid
from EncounterInformation as enc inner join 
     FileAllocation as fl
     on enc.encounterIndexId = fl.encounterid
limit 20;
```

The first query runs in 0.760 seconds on MYSQL while second one runs in 0.509 seconds surprisingly.

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin But what if I don't want to use it?

Comment: How is between '0.760' and '0.509' is considered as _much longer_?

Comment: @tcadidot0 Okay it's not much longer but what I meant is that the first one should take much lesser time which it isn't.Please don't go into the grammer. All I mean is that why is join not proving to be expensive over here?

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: @Strawberry Can you please elaborate why? Shouldn't it take top 20 matching rows in the table?

Comment: Skip the `limit` and see what happens...

Comment: No. Rows in a relational database represent unordered sets. MySQL is at liberty to choose any 20 rows. In practice it tends to fall back on internal indexes, which may or may not correspond with your expectations. Short answer; always include an ORDER BY clause with LIMIT.

Comment: "0.760 seconds" - It should rather be something like 0.760 milliseconds, unless you have really large data per row or some fancy storage engine.

Comment: @Strawberry using order by took even longer.Moreover going by your statement how do you explain when we use limit 10,20 . how does It decide 10th index if "it can choose any 20 rows"?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Please don't go into the intricacies. Both are in same unit so it doesn't matter.

Comment: What I say is that almost one second is way to much for a query like this. But since we know nothing about the table, we can't tell you anything. MySQL performance questions should always include EXPLAIN result and CREATE statements.

Comment: @Strawberry see this The Edit Part https://stackoverflow.com/a/6736573/8087656

Comment: @PaulSpiegel It has around 20000 rows.

Comment: @abhihacker02 So now you have choice - return a limited number of 'quasi-random' rows in a very fast time, or return the rows you actually expect in a longer timeframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many reasons why measured performance between two queries might be different:

- The execution plans for the queries (the dominant factor)
- The size of the data being returned (perhaps `mrn` is a string that is really long for the result set in the first query but not the second)
- Other database activity, that locks tables and indexes
- Other server activity
- Data and index caches that are pre-loaded -- either in the database itself or in the underlying OS components

Your observation is correct.  The first should be faster than the second.  More importantly though is the observation that this simply does not make sense for your simple query:

> The first query runs in 0.760 seconds
>
> ```
> select mrn
> from EncounterInformation
> limit 20;
> ```

The work done for this would typically be to load one data page (or maybe a handful).  That would only consistently take 0.760 seconds if:

- You had really slow data storage (think "carrier pigeons").
- `EncounterInformation` is a view and not a table.
- You don't understand timings.

If the difference is between 0.760 **milli**seconds and 0.509 milliseconds, then the difference is really small and likely due to other issues -- warm caches, other activity on the server, other database activity.

It is also possible that you are measuring *elapsed* time and not database time, so network congestion could potentially be an issue.

If you are querying views, all bets are off without knowing what the views are.  In fact, if you care about performance you should be including the execution plan in the question.

I can't explain the difference.  What I can say is that your observation is reasonable, but your question lacks lots of information that suggests you need to learn more about how to understand timings.  I would suggest that you start with learning about `explain`.

Comment: I agree with your answer.Just a small question.Can you Please explain how does LIMIT works without order by because after using explain LIMIT without order by scans the whole table.

Comment: @abhihacker02 . . . It returns arbitrary rows, which should be the first rows from the query being executed.